# Using kdiff3 as default git diff viewer on Mac OS

Tags: terminal, git

I have kdiff3 installed on my Mac (Version 0.9.97, 64 bit). Here's my ~/.gitconfig:

```
[filter "media"]
    required = true
    clean = git media clean %f
    smudge = git media smudge %f
[user]
    name = My Name
    email = me@example.com

[core]
    editor = atom --wait
[merge]
    tool = kdiff3
[mergetool "kdiff3"]
    path = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
[diff]
    tool = kdiff3
[difftool "kdiff3"]
    path = /Applications/kdiff3.app/Contents/MacOS/kdiff3
```

Everything seems to be fine, except for the fact that when I do `git diff`, I see the output of the console diff. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible to update your Git and use `git difftool` ([docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)) instead?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use

`git diff myfile.txt`

but

`git difftool myfile.txt`.